# Airsoft question on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There was a new Sports.SE question recently: [How does 'airbreak' work on airsoft guns?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/601/how-does-airbreak-works-on-airsoft-guns)

While this question clearly relates to equipment, does this particular question fits into any sport - it doesn't directly relate to sports like skeet shooting or Olympic target shooting.

Is this particular question on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

To the extend that airsoft is a sport, then this would be on-topic for the site. I know a lot of people spends a lot of time on this and takes it very seriously... And you can probably find more arenas for airsoft games than for skeet shooting - at least in Denmark.

I find it difficult to vote airsoft not-a-sport, but I'l be very happy to hear other opinions on this..

Comment: Good point - I wasn't sure if it was a sport or not, hence this question. :)

Comment: And as you can see, I'm not to sure either :-)

Comment: There's also a [firearms.se] site, but that doesn't mean firearms are necessarily off topic here.

Comment: Do we have a definition for what we are considering a sport?

Comment: @MichaelMyers, unfortunately, I hear that the Firearms site went away: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/

Comment: @Matt to answer your question, http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/162 and http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/56

Answer (score 1):

There's a proposal of [Airsoft](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51265/airsoft) on Area51 currently and the same question has surfaced. Let me post some other example questions:

- How to prepare booby traps that are quick and easy to install?
- What winter clothing lets you feel hits while still keeping you warm in bad weather?
- How to maintain a hi-cap mag to keep it from jamming?
- What is the best way to stop goggles fogging up?
- My hop-up makes the balls curve to the side. How do I fix it?
- Where to purchase a replacement input valve for a WE M9 magazine in the UK?
- How do I replace the barrel of an ICS L85?
- Which brands of magazines are compatible with the ICS MP5?

This represents a somewhat larger sample than the one question listed here. Are these good fit for your site or not?

Comment: At first glance, I have no problem with these questions as long as they contribute to our scope of sports. Keep in mind that there is usually overlap among SE sites...so if Airsoft is its own SE site someday, the expertise for Airsoft questions will be specialized at Airsoft SE, not Sports SE, and questions may be on-topic for both sites.